# ¿Mi calculadora detecté divisiónes por 0?

Tags: javascript

```js
function show(){

  inp.value = eval(inp.value)
  



}
```

La cosa es que cuando show sea llamada necesito que cuándo detecte una división por 0 me ponga en el input no es divisible lo que hace ahora es simplemente evaluar el texto que está dentro el input con eval

Comment: Una division por cero en `javascript` siempre te dara `Infinity`, exceptuando la division entre 0 con 0 la cual da un `NaN`.

Comment: Ah bueno o `-Infinity`.

Comment: y tu funcion eval?, inserta todo el codigo relacionado a tu problema

Comment: No se bajo que circunstancias estas haciendo esto pero te aconsejo que tengas cuidado con lo que estas tratando de implementar, nunca permitas que `eval` ejecute el input de un usuario arbitrariamente y mucho menos si no implementas ningún tipo de saneamiento del input, se la estarías dejando muy fácil a un atacante.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es realizar operaciones matemáticas te recomiendo usar expresiones regulares tanto para validar que sean operaciones matemáticas como para extraer la información que necesitas y hacer el computo de forma segura